# How can I call a environnement variable declared in my service.yml?

Tags: php, environment-variables, symfony4

I'm working on a symfony project that need to be refactorized. 
I'm trying to call a environnement variable declared in servces.yml
When i'm running `php bin/console debug:container --parameters` I can see the variables.

I tried `$this->getParameters('param_name');`
When I'm dumping them in a controller it's working fine but when i'm trying to access them from a service it is failing -> `Method 'getParameter' not found in 'TwitterService'`
I thought that this method was native in symfony.

Here is my twitter service

````
```namespace App\Services;
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

/**
 * Class TwitterService.
 */
class TwitterService
{
    /** @const int NUMBER_OF_TWEETS */
    private const NUMBER_OF_TWEETS = 2;

    /**
     * @param string $twitterID
     *
     * @return array|object
     */
    public function getTwitterFeed($twitterID = 'RISKandMe')
    {
        // @todo move config to .env
        $consumerKey = $this->getParameter('consumer_key');
        $consumerSecret = $this->getParameter('consumer_secret');
        $accessToken = $this->getParameter('access_token');
        $accessTokenSecret = $this->getParameter('access_token');
        // Authenticate with twitter
        $twitterConnection = new TwitterOAuth(
            $consumerKey,
            $consumerSecret,
            $accessToken,
            $accessTokenSecret
        );
        // Get the user timeline feeds

        return $twitterConnection->get(
            'statuses/user_timeline',
            [
                'screen_name' => $twitterID,
                'count' => self::NUMBER_OF_TWEETS,
                'exclude_replies' => false,
            ]
        );
    }
}
````

Here is my services.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'fr'
    api_key_validity: '%env(int:APIKEYVALIDITY)%'
    activation_delay: '%env(int:ACTIVATIONDELAY)%'
    gophish_api_key: '%env(GOPHISHAPIKEY)%'
    gophish_server: '%env(GOPHISHSERVER)%'
    gophish_white_list: '%env(GOPHISHWHITELIST)%'
    mailjet_public: '%env(MAILJET_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    mailjet_secret: '%env(MAILJET_PRIVATE_KEY)%'
    sender_address: '%env(SENDER_ADDRESS)%'
    sender_name: '%env(SENDER_NAME)%'
    consumer_key: '%env(CONSUMER_KEY)%'
    consumer_secret: '%env(CONSUMER_SECRET)%'
    access_token: '%env(ACCESS_TOKEN)%'
    access_token_secret: '%env(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)%'
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
#    user_listener:
#        class: App\EntityListener\UserListener
#        arguments: ['@logger']
#        tags:
#            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener,entity: App\Entity\User}
#
    form_authenticator:
          class: App\Security\FormAuthenticator
          arguments: ["@logger","@router","@security.password_encoder","@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager",CsrfTokenManagerInterface]
    token_authenticator:
          class: App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
          arguments: ["@logger","@router","@security.password_encoder","@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager",CsrfTokenManagerInterface,ParameterBagInterface]
    DbUserProvider:
        class: App\Security\DbUserProvider

    FickleUserProvider:
        class: App\Security\FickleUserProvider    

    BackEndUserProvider:
        class: App\Security\BackEndUserProvider    

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
    App\Controller\Services\Helper:
        arguments: ['@logger','@router','@security.password_encoder','@mailer','@session','@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    App\Controller\Services\GoPhish:
        arguments: []
        tags: []
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/DashboardController.php'
        arguments: ["@logger","@router","@security.password_encoder",'@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager',App\Controller\Services\Helper]
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
#    session.listener:
#        class: App\Listeners\SessionListener
#        tags:
#            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
#    user.activity_listener:
#        class: App\Listeners\ActivityListener
#       tags:
#            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '%env(string:DBCONNEXIONPARAMETERS)%'
            - { db_table: 'ht_session', db_username: '%env(string:DBUSER)%', db_password: '%env(string:DBPASSWORD)%'}
    app.services.twitter:
        class: App\Services\TwitterService
```

If someone has any idea they would be more than appreciated.

Thank you very much for you attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$this->getParameter()` helper function is only available in controllers extending from the class `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;`.

In order to access a container-parameter in your service you need to inject or autowire it into your service.

```
# services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            # schema -> [constructor-variable name]: [parameter name]
            $consumerSecret: '%consumer_secret%' 
            $consumerKey: '%consumer_key%'
            # [..]
```

Then use them as follows:

```php
class TwitterService
{
    private $csonsumerSecret;
    private $consumerKey;

    public function __construct(
        string $consumerKey,
        string $consumerSecret,
        // [..]
    ) {
        $this->consumerKey = $consumerKey;
        $this->consumerSecret = $consumerSecret;
        // [..]
    }

    public function getTwitterFeed($twitterID = 'RISKandMe')
    {
       $twitterConnection = new TwitterOAuth(
            $this->consumerKey,
            $this->consumerSecret,
            // [..]
        );
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much man ! I missed this part in symfony docs
Sorry for the disturbance

Comment: I need to do the same for the senders in mailer service but I have different senders depending if i'm in test or prod env. I have a test/prod folder in config where there's a swiftmailer.yml in each. Should I declare the parameters in them or directly in the service.yaml ?  Thank you a lot. Sorry again..

Comment: I've added the prod sender in service.yaml and added an override in config/test/swiftmailer.yaml with ```delivery_addresses: ['%env(TEST_SENDER_ADDRESS)%']```